# curious, layout problem package: titlesec

Tags: errors, header-footer, titlesec, layout

My problem is the following. I'm currently working on my Bachelor thesis with Overleaf. I'm trying to do the same layout as a friend of mine. But even if I copy his project completly as it is. I get the following error:

> package titlesec error: Not allowed in easy settings

If I put everything which is related to this package in a comment it works as it should. If I open the same project in "sharelatex" it works. 
If my friend copys my project (which is a copy of his project) it stops working at his computer as well. When I remove the `*` on every command it is possible to compile but I lose the function of the star.

Veryyyyy curious. Does someone has a glue what to do to make it run on Overleaf again?

Here is the part of the header which is causing the problem:

```latex
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\scshape\rmfamily\centering}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{15ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{7ex plus .2ex}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
```

Minimalexample:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, english, a4paper, toc=indentunnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english, german]{babel}  

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp} %for example copyright

\usepackage{blindtext}  % Beispieltext


%----------SEITENLAYOUT-----------%

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[total={5.8in, 8.5in}]{geometry}

%--------Section headings---------%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\scshape\rmfamily\centering}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{15ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{7ex plus .2ex}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\begin{document}
1234567890
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It sounds like the error message you're getting is generated by code contained in the document class file. Please do tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Compare the log-file of the working version of your friend with your log-file.

Comment: Please also tell us more about any differences in computing setups between your and your friend. E.g., does he/she get a similar error message? Does she compile her document on Overleaf as well, or on a different platform? If it's the latter, which TeX platform does your friend use?

Comment: My document class is also the same as his: 
It's: 
~\documentclass[10pt, english, a4paper, toc=indentunnumbered]{scrartcl}~

Comment: my log file is full of the errors and the working version is not. Or what exactly do you want me to compare? @ Ulrike Fischer

My friend also uses Overleaf so this is not the difference. We're both using Windows7. No my friend doens't get any error message unless I'm opening a new code and try to run it -> get a error message -> he copys my programm (which is exactly the same as his before) he runs it and then he gets the same error message as I do.

Comment: Could you post a minimal, yet complete, code reproducing the error?

Comment: Check for version differences. I bet the non-working version uses a newer texlive. titlesec is no longer compatible with the KOMA-classes, the KOMA-classes removed some patches.

Answer (score 1):

The KOMA classes are no longer compatible with titlesec. Some patches which more or less made it working have been removed. This means that this here compiles with texlive 2018 but not with a current texlive 2019:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{}

\begin{document}
\section{abc}
\end{document}
```

You can check your log-files for the texlive version used. My guess is that you are using a newer one (overleaf switched some time ago) and that your friend is using the option of a newer texlive too when copying the project back.

Comment: that means I need to use a diffrent package then titlesec? Can you recommend one which is doing the exact same thing as I did? 
And you're right, his overleaf is using texlife2018 and me 2019. 
I think even more convenient for me would it be to change this? 
Thank all of you so much!

Comment: The KOMA-classes have enough in-built features to setup the sections. You only need to use them. If you prefer titlesec, don't use the class scrartcl (also in older texlive this wasn't recommended) but e.g. article.

Comment: So I replace "scrartcl" with "KOMA"? 
And then I have to use other commands for dooing the job done before with the titlesec package?

Comment: scrartcl *is* a KOMA-class. Check scrguide.pdf for a documentation.